# Unable to run nifi in window server 2016

Tags: apache-nifi

I am not able to run nifi in window server 2016 even though I change to java 8

*java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)*

```
C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\nifi-1.16.1-bin\nifi-1.16.1\bin>run-nifi.bat
2022-05-11 23:20:58,804 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2022-05-11 23:20:58,804 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1
2022-05-11 23:20:58,804 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\conf;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\nifi-api-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\nifi-properties-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\nifi-property-utils-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\nifi-stateless-api-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\nifi-stateless-bootstrap-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Dcurator-log-only-first-connection-issue-as-error-level=true -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dzookeeper.admin.enableServer=false -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=54233 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\bin\..\\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi
2022-05-11 23:20:59,078 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2022-05-11 23:20:59,078 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\Users\HelloWorld\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2022-05-11 23:20:59,078 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 964
```

Comment: Look at these warning messages (`Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read...`)